# c# postgresql multiple add values

Tags: c#, postgresql

I'm playing with a PostgreSQL and c#. I'm entering multiple .AddWithValues() to fill in all of the data. This might get hairy, considering a real database will have more keys. **Is there a way to combine multiple AddWithValues()s into a single line or operation?**

Here is my code:

```
//Open the connection

//Made the id as a Guid. For now just using var id = new Guid()

//Insert multiple rows
using(var command = new NpgsqlCommand())
{
     command.Connection = connection;
     command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO testschema.testtable" +
                        "(name, id, number)" +
                        "VALUES (@name, @id, @number)";
     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", "Greg");
     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("number", 7);
     command.ExecuteNonQuery(); //Needs to be inside the loop

     //TODO: have the command text and parameters constructed once(Using the Parameters.Add for the parameters
     // and change values in the loop.

     //Also should have one connection open. So open just before the loop and close it after
 }

 //Close the connection
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use type definitions? `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Parameter", SqlDbType.Decimal, 11, 4).Value = MyDecimalVariable;`

Comment: I saw that in the Add(), but how do you handle the 3rd parameter, the length? If I have a Text type, shouldn't it be variable in size? Or is that 11 mean that the value I'm inputting will be 11 characters in size?